# calculate the average of a vector with one input argument and find the average of the following vector: [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, vector, stdvector

How can I solve this with javascript? provide me a better solution. someone help me. I am confused about the vector. and it's input takes one argument

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

ifstream numbers;
numbers.open("G:\\numbers.dat"); // just a file of 10 integers.
int i;
vector<float> vectors;

while(numbers >> i) {
    vectors.push_back(i);
}

for(int n=0; n < vectors.size(); ++n ){
    cout << vectors[n] << endl;
}

int avg;
for(int k=0; k < vectors.size(); ++k){
    // not sure what to put here basically.
    cout << avg << endl;
}


numbers.close();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: why javascript?

Comment: @NinaScholz I can't do it with javascript. I want to solve it with javascript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript

Comment: Tactical note: when computing an average you don't need a container. Simply sum up the values as they are given and keep a count of the number of items summed so you can divide the sum by the count at the end.

Comment: It's just a requirement.

Comment: "_How can I solve this without using PHP?_" - and then you write C++ code but want javascript?

Comment: @user4581301 It's a vector. so I am confused. do I need to solve it in this way?

Comment: @RakiburRahman `// not sure what to put here basically.` -- `std::cout << std::accumulate(vectors.begin(), vectors.end(), 0.0f) / vectors.size();` -- Otherwise I have no idea what you're really asking here.

Comment: "_do I need to solve it in this way?_" - No, you don't need to store the numbers in a `vector`. Just read them from the file and sum them up while counting how many you've read. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/E6cv1M87M)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you do it in JS:

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
console.log(arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length)
```

Here's how you do it in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>  
#include <iterator>  
#include <numeric>   

int main() {
  const int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  std::cout << 
      std::accumulate(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0.0) / std::size(arr) << '\n';
}
```

Here's how you do it in C:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  const size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
  double sum = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) sum += arr[i];
  printf("%.2f\n", sum / size);
}
```

Here's how you do it in Python:

```py
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(sum(arr)/len(arr))
```

Here's how you do it in Rust:

```rust
fn main() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let sum : i32 = arr.iter().sum();
    println!("{}", sum as f64 / arr.len() as f64);
}
```

Here's how you do it in golang:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    sum := 0.0;
    for _, n := range arr {
        sum += float64(n);
    }
    
    fmt.Printf("%f\n", sum / float64(len(arr)));
}
```

Here's how to do it in C#:

```cs
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        System.Console.WriteLine(arr.Average());
    }
}
```

Here's how to do it in Java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        System.out.println(getAverage(arr));
    }

    public static double getAverage(int[] arr) {
        return Arrays.stream(arr)
                .average()
                .getAsDouble();
    }
}
```

Here's how you do it in Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val arr = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    println(arr.average());
}
```

Here's how you do it in Ruby:

```rb
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
average = arr.sum(0.0) / arr.size;
puts average;
```

Here's how you do it in Swift:

```swift
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let sum = arr.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
let average = Double(sum) / Double(arr.count)

print(average)
```